# Selecting top from union results in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, union

I'm currently studying about the optimizer in SQL Server, and I have a question about selecting data from union results.

If I execute the query below

```
SELECT  TOP (100) ...
FROM (
    SELECT  ... FROM TBL1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ... FROM TBL2
) AS A
ORDER BY COL1, COL2
```

I thought (this is what I learned) the optimizer inside changes this query into the query below, so it could read at most 100 rows from each table.

```
SELECT  TOP (100) ...
FROM (
    SELECT  TOP (100) ... FROM TBL1 ORDER BY COL1, COL2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  TOP (100) ... FROM TBL2 ORDER BY COL1, COL2
) AS A
ORDER BY COL1, COL2
```

But, as I checked out the execution plan, the optimizer read the whole data from both tables (with clustered index scan) and sorted them.

Can anyone tell me how it works inside? Is there any specific reason the optimizer scans the whole table?

Answer (score 1):

There is an order of Precedence in SQL. According to it `TOP()` is evaluated after the `ORDER BY` clause. Therefore, all the records are picked first, then ordered, and then only the top 100 is selected.
You can refer to this on this site.

[SQL Select Precedence](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/data-manipulation/what-is-the-correct-sql-order-of-precedence/)